# GET batch job execution results from Spring XD

Tags: rest, spring-xd

Spring XD has a very interesting API for providing batch jobs creation/deployment/undeployment.

But, I was wondering why Spring XD is not proposing in its REST Api a GET method to access the result dataset of a job execution (and step execution) ?

Do I need to plug another Spring MVC application to display my batch jobs results ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked [admin ui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#adminui)?

Comment: yes. And I don't see what i need.

Comment: What exactly do you want to be exposed? Since batch jobs could be doing just about anything, it is difficult to come up with a generic API. May I suggest you open a bug/enhancement request at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/XD (which sadly is down atm). A github ticket can be opened instead at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/issues?state=closed

Comment: Note that there are `job execution list`, `job execution display`, `job execution step list`, `job execution step display`, `job execution step progress` commands in the XD shell (with equivalent REST APIs), this may be what you are looking for

Comment: hi. In fact, I thought that all batch jobs produced datasets in the end, and I wanted to have a REST GET url to be able to retrieve each job/step instance dataset.